# Wrappers around lambda expressions

Tags: python, lambda

I have functions in python that take two inputs, do some manipulations, and return two outputs. I would like to rearrange the output arguments, so I wrote a wrapper function around the original function that creates a new function with the new output order

```
def rotate(f):
    h = lambda x,y: -f(x,y)[1], f(x,y)[0]
    return h

f = lambda x, y: (-y, x)
h = rotate(f)
```

However, this is giving an error message:

```
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

`x` is an argument to a lambda expression, so why does it have to be defined?

The expected behavior is that `h` should be a new function that is identical to `lambda x,y: (-x,-y)`

Comment: Since you are naming your functions (ie they are not anonymous), I would avoid using `lambda` and use `def` instead. [Lambda forms](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms) are for small *anonymous* functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add parentheses around the lambda expression:

```
h = lambda x,y: (-f(x,y)[1], f(x,y)[0])
```

Otherwise, Python interprets the code as:

```
h = (lambda x,y: -f(x,y)[1]), f(x,y)[0]
```

and `h` is a 2-tuple.

Answer (score 5):

There is problem with precedence. Just use additional parentheses:

```
def rotate(f):
    h = lambda x,y: (-f(x,y)[1], f(x,y)[0])
    return h
```